# Jenkins Android emulator is running because of the outdated SDK. How I can update it on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, android-emulator-plugin

I am using jenkins on my local system and added an android emulator plugin but it is giving me error for the outdated SDK.

```
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk f04a1c2fe717dc9b6a3a329636f418e3dc853585 # timeout=10
[android] Outdated SDK Tools found. Upgrading from '26.1.1' to 'build 6609375'
[android] Android SDK installation failed
[android] hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstallationException: Failed to download Android SDK
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.doInstall(SdkInstaller.java:91)
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.install(SdkInstaller.java:72)
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.AndroidEmulator.setUp(AndroidEmulator.java:278)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to donwload SDK archive
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.installBasicSdk(SdkInstaller.java:189)
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.doInstall(SdkInstaller.java:89)
    ... 8 more

Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with the exactly same issue on ubuntu server now.
What I've done - manually downloaded sdk tools and installed them in my /usr/lib/android-sdk folder

- `wget -O sdk-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip`
- `sudo apt install unzip`
- `unzip sdk-tools.zip`

and this issue disappeared on jenkins for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow *steps*:

1. Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Scroll to bottom
2. un-check the `Automatically install Android components when required`

Comment: If the issue is an outdated SDK, wouldn’t you want the components updated? Or is the issue that the components are getting out ahead of the SDK? Adding some explanation here will help future readers understand the concept here.

Comment: @JeremyCaney everything needed will be downloaded automatically during the next steps of the script (at least it is in my case - flutter mobile app ;)) - I've just added my proposal to fix this particular step for those, who need to unblock Jenkins. In general, it looks like that need to be reported as an issue in the "Android Emulator" Jenkins plugin repo.

Comment: It is a known issue of the plugin https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65625?jql=component%3D15725